# How to use "Sync" to transfer files?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-galaxy-s-6

The app "Sync" by Bittorrent claim to allow sync between devices without a cloud but when I click the "link device" on either of the two devies I'm trying to connect to the other I get a camera screen.  What am I missing?

Comment: Quick guess: the barcode created on the other device to be scanned, in order to "authenticate" the two?

Comment: Just like @Izzy said, Sync gives you a barcode that you can scan on other devices to share a folder.